# empty observable subscribed, but onNext not called?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I want an Observable that doesnt do anything except that when subscribed to, the observer's onNext callback is invoked.  I think I found that with Observable.empty(), but the following does not result in the observer's onNext callback being invoked:

```
Observable<Void> emptyObservable = Observable.empty();
emptyObservable.subscribe(passedinObserver);
```

passedInObserver was defined:

```
Observer<Void> passedinObserver = new Observer<Void> {
        @Override public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("onNext called");
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Observable.just(null)` or any value since you are going to ingore the value anyway. However, it appears you want to perform additional work when values travel through an observable sequence, so you can use `doOnNext()`:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.doOnNext(v -> Log.d("onNext called"))
.map(v -> v * v)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

`onNext` doesn't get called, `onCompleted` does for this type of `Observable`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the other answers, since `empty` only calls `onCompleted` without calling `onNext`, maybe you just want to do your work in `onCompleted` rather than in `onNext`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Observable.just(...)`. It will return one value and thus call `.onNext(...)`.

Comment: @MichałK - I'm more a C# developer. Sorry about that. Fixed.